# How to check date in one cell and enter string in another cell based on outcome?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following table (input in cells not formatted as a table) in excel:

| Action | Status | Raised | Scheduled Completion | Completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| An Action | Late | 01/04/2023 | 10/01/2023 |  |
| Another Action | Imminent | 01/04/2023 | 30/04/2023 |  |
| Another Action | Scheduled | 01/04/2023 | 31/05/2023 |  |
| Another Action | Complete | 01/04/2023 | 30/04/2023 | 20/04/2023 |
| Another Action | Late Complete | 01/04/2023 | 10/04/2023 | 20/04/2023 |

I am trying to have the status automatically update with one of the listed status's whenever a date is input in the scheduled completion or completed columns. How I've tried doing this is with a formula and conditional formatting however I can't get it to work. Would VBA be a better way to do this? If so, how would I go about coding that? I have very little experience with VBA.

This is the formula I've attempted to make work (to no avail):
`=IF(D1>TODAY()+30, "Scheduled", "") IF(D1<TODAY(), "Late","") IF(D1>TODAY() AND(D1>TODAY()+30), "Imminent", "") IF(E1>D1,"Late Complete",""),IF(E1<=D1, "Complete","")`
Obviously this is in relation to one row and is entered into the cell in the status column. I then have some conditional formatting rules set up to highlight the cells in the status column with the relevant colour.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the `IFS()` function ... this lets you chain conditions, rather than nesting them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I've managed to progress it a little in that I'm no longer getting an immediate error but I now have a #NAME error when I use the following formula ```=IFS(D1>TODAY()+30, "Scheduled", D1<TODAY(), "Late", AND(D1>TODAY(),D1>TODAY()+30), "Imminent", E1>D1,"Late Complete",E1<=D1, "Complete")``` 
Do you know why this is?

Comment: Does a simple =IFS() formula work? What version of Excel are you on? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45?ns=excel&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zxl900&helpid=xlmain11.chm60655&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us Also, I think the 3rd condition should be `AND(D1>TODAY(),D1<TODAY()+30)`. You can add a final entry of `...,TRUE,"Uncategorized")` to handle the possibility that none of the conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on Excel 2016 so the IFS function doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is checking >Today()+30 = "Imminent", you probably want <Today()+30 = "Imminent"

Your formulas should always check whether E is blank, or rearrange your formula so that the formulas which test both column D and column E come first.

Both of these formulas should be equivalent, whichever is easier to follow:

```
=IF(D2="","",
IF(AND(E2="",D2>TODAY()+30),"Scheduled",
IF(AND(E2="",D2<TODAY()),"Late",
IF(AND(E2="",D2>TODAY(),D2<TODAY()+30),"Imminent",
IF(AND(E2<>"",E2>D2),"Late Complete",
IF(AND(E2<>"",E2<=D2),"Complete",""))))))
```

Also in the formula you can use ALT + Enter to separate your formula into lines, it makes these nested formulas easier to follow

```
=IF(D2="","",
IF(E2="",
IF(D2>TODAY()+30, "Scheduled",
IF(D2<TODAY(), "Late",
IF(AND(D2>TODAY(),D2<TODAY()+30), "Imminent"))),
IF(E2<>"",
IF(E2>D2,"Late Complete",
IF(E2<=D2, "Complete","")))))
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, this pretty much solves my issue. Do you know if there's a way I can incorporate an option whereby it doesn't default to "Late" in the status if there are no dates in columns C, D or E?

Comment: I've edited the above just to check whether D2 is blank. You could also change the first line of the formula to something like `IF(D2="","No scheduled date",` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand where you want to go, but I am not sure what you mean with "AND(D1>TODAY(),D1>TODAY()+30), "Imminent"". If D1 is more than today+30, then it is also more than today.

I have made a variant of what I think you want to achieve, and assumed that Imminent is for D1 to be between today+30 and today as today+30 was the first statement for "Scheduled".

> =IF(D2>TODAY()+30;"Scheduled";IF(D2<TODAY();"Late";IF(D2>TODAY();"Imminent";IF(E2>D2;"Late
> Complete";IF(E2<=D2;"Complete";"")))))

This will go through the logic statements one by one until one is true.

I use D2 and E2 as the first row is text. You may also need to change ; to , depending on EU vs. US version of excel.

Comment: Hi, thanks this solves 90% of my issue. The only problem I have now is that it does not recognise when I have a completed date. When I enter one, it does not change the status. Also, thanks for the heads up about the ; as I did need to change those to , :)

Comment: Is this when you have a completed date and not a scheduled date? Or is both there?

Comment: It's when I have both there. Effectively, I want to be able to enter the completed date and the status change to either 'Complete' or 'Late Complete' depending on what the date of completion is.

Comment: The conditions for the logic statements needs to be adjusted then. Try to change the last statement E2<=D2;"Complete" to E2<>"";"Complete"

Answer (score 0):

I would think this would benefit from some helper columns for clarity?
Something like this off to the right (again working with the limitation of not using IFS):

| complete? | late? | soon? | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| =E2 > 0 | =MAX(TODAY(), E2) > D2 | =AND(NOT(G2), NOT(F2), TODAY() + 30 > D2) | =IF(H2, "Imminent", IF(F2, IF(G2, "Complete Late", "Complete"), IF(G2, "Late", "Scheduled"))) |